# Why is Django not rendering all HTML elements?

Tags: python, html, django, tinymce

I installed TinyMCE in my Django project so I can write a post with formatting such as bulleted lists, tables, etc. When I try to render the text box, it some elements (like a bullet) is missing, and has no formatting.

TinyMCE is indeed working, as I can get a code block with syntax highlighting, but for some reason bulleted lists and even bold just appear as normal text.

I put the safe flag as well.

Answer (score -1):

Open `catalog/views.py` and note that the file already imports the `render()` shortcut function to generate an HTML file using a template and the data from django.

Create your views here:

```
Shortcuts import render #
```

The first line imports the model classes that we'll use to access data in all our views.

Comment: I fail to see the relevance to my question. Try posting a legitimate answer rather than copy-pasting from a tutorial and not even linking said tutorial.